# Retrieving hierachical data from SQL to post as JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, zend-framework2

I have the following result set from a mysql query:

```
  id|parent_id|ordering
  83|   0     |0
  84|  83     |1
  85|  83     |2
  86|  83     |3
6721|  83     |6
6722|  83     |7
5643|  83     |8
 100|  5643   |9
5641|  83     |10
6067|  5641   |11
  95|  5641   |12
  94|  5641   |13
6723|  5641   |14
6724|  5641   |15
6068|  5641   |18
  90|  83     |19
  91|  90     |20
  92|  90     |21
6725|  90     |22
5482|  83     |23
5483|  5482   |24
 106|  25     |25
 108|  106    |26
```

I need to parse this result set into JSON so I can output as part of a mobile web api. The output needs to be a specific format:

```
83:{
    children :{
         84:{ children:{}},
         85:{ children:{}},
         86:{ children:{}},
         6721:{ children:{}},
         6722:{ children:{}},
         5643:{ children:{
                100:children{}
                }
              },
         5641:{ children:{
                6067:{children:{}},
                95:{children:{}},
                94:{children:{}},
                6723:{children:{}},
                6724:{children:{}},
                6068:{children:{}}
                }
         },
         90:{ children:{
              91:{children:{}},
              92:{children:{}},
              6725:{children:{}}
              }
         },
         5482:{ children:{5783}},
    }
}
```

I know the root node is the one where the parent_id is ZERO. The idea is to create a children object that contains a nodes' children, or is empty if no children exist. I do not understand how to parse the result set to return a json object that follows the above spec. I have more data in the same table that varies in size, so creating for loops to iterate through this dataset will not work for every dataset. Im handling this data in php, more specifically ZF2.

Comment: you've already answered your question: you format your PHP array/object the same way you want your JSON to appear.

Comment: @MarcB I see the format, but parsing the result set dynamically to get it into that format is where I am having problems